# How to use/enable PHP extensions for CLI on swisscomdev/cloudfoundry php_buildback?

Tags: symfony, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

** **EDIT** **

For several cases we need to call Symfony commands on a deployed CloudFoundry app. Symfony commands are php scripts which are called with the PHP CLI.

One example is `bin/console doctrine:schema:update` (but could be user generation, cache clearing etc.)

So for our app we need both, fpm and cli enabled. This is done with:

```
  "PHP_MODULES": [
"fpm",
"cli"]
```

in options.json.

After connecting to the app with `cf ssh` I change to app directory and I call `php/bin/php doctrine:schema:update` this results in a ClassNotFound: PDO issue.

During staging these commands are called successfully.

I checked that for PHP CLI the PDO extension is not available (by checking php -i) although I have mentioned it in options.json.

```
"PHP_EXTENSIONS": [
 ...
 "pdo",
 "pdo_mysql",
 ...]
```

How to enable extensions for CLI and FPM on one app? And is it theoretically possible to have different extensions for CLI and FPM and as well different user-php.ini s to fully/particularly override php.ini of CLI and FPM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So for our app we need both, fpm and cli enabled. This is done with:
>
> "PHP_MODULES": [ "fpm", "cli"]
>
> in options.json.

This is something that we should probably clean up in the build pack.  I do not believe it's (PHP_MODULES) actually used any more.

Maybe a year or more ago, the build pack switched how it downloads PHP.  It would previously download individual components modules & extensions.  Now it just downloads everything at once.  This actually ends up being faster since it's one larger download vs many smaller downloads, and bandwidth is generally very fast for build pack downloads.

Worth mentioning that while PHP_EXTENSIONS no longer triggers what to download it is still used in terms of what extensions get enabled in php.ini.  Thus you still need to set that or indicate extensions through composer.

> After connecting to the app with cf ssh

I believe that this is the issue.  You need to source the build pack env variables so that the env is configured properly.

Ex:

```
vcap@359b74ff-686c-494e-4a1e-46a9c420f262:~$ php
bash: php: command not found

vcap@359b74ff-686c-494e-4a1e-46a9c420f262:~$ HOME=$HOME/app source app/.profile.d/bp_env_vars.sh
vcap@359b74ff-686c-494e-4a1e-46a9c420f262:~$ php -v
PHP 5.6.26 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2016 22:24:22)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Staging does this automatically as does runtime for your app.  Unfortunately `cf ssh` does not.

**UPDATE:**

A slightly easier way to do this is to run `cf ssh myapp -t -c "/tmp/lifecycle/launcher /home/vcap/app bash ''"`.  This will open a bash shell and it lets the lifecycle launcher handle sourcing & setting up the environment.

> And is it theoretically possible to have different extensions for CLI and FPM and as well different user-php.ini s to fully/particularly override php.ini of CLI and FPM?

Sure.  By default, we download and install all extensions.  Thus you just need a different php.ini (or some other setting to enable that extension) in which you enable your alternate set of extensions.

When you `cf ssh` into the container, you could copy the existing php.ini somewhere else and edit it for your CLI needs.  Then reference that php-alt.ini when you run your CLI commands.

Comment: wow, that was a tough one! i'd never been able to figure that out! do you think it's possible to add this extra command to the cf ssh command somehow? because if it's done in staging and app runtime it looks like it should be done for cf ssh as well.

Comment: created an github issue with the php buildpack - but not sure whether this is the right adress to point the issue to. https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/issues/182

Comment: To my knowledge, it's something the platform would need to do.  Other build packs that utilize `.profile.d` scripts for env setup (which is most) have the same limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Never did this but does enabling the php cli in PHP_MODULES (https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/buildpacks/php/gsg-php-config.html) help?

Comment: ah, that looks fantastic - should have seen this - will try and provide feedback.

Comment: I provided `"PHP_MODULES": [
    "fpm",
    "cli"
  ]` - but not sure that it really got installed - looks and behaves like before :-(